# Wordpress primary menu alignment

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I am learning css and try to do a wordpress. I did a child theme as recommended, and works on implementation.
I have a problem on menu alignment ; The primary menu is actually on the left side. I would like to put it on the right side. I know that I could use secondary menu but my question is just to understand how to modify a wordpress by css :)

The template is Reykjavik.

I tried vary solutions in the **style.css** child folder, like :

`.main-navigation {
     margin: auto;
 }`

to enlarge the main navigation zone, and next

`.main-navigation-container ul {
    float: right;
}`

to put the menu in the right side of the screen but nothing works...
Also proved to work on padding but nothing changed..

[image: my screen]

Are you able to tell me were I'm doing something wrong please ?

Thank you for your help,

Jerry

**Edit :**

`

```
    <button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="menu-primary" aria-expanded="true">Menu</button>

    <div id="site-navigation-container" class="main-navigation-container">
    <div class="mobile-search-form"><form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">
            <label>
                <span class="screen-reader-text">Rechercher&nbsp;:</span>
                <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Recherche…" value="" name="s">
            </label>
            <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Rechercher">
        </form></div><div class="menu"><ul id="menu-primary" class="menu-primary" aria-expanded="true"><li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/" aria-current="page">Accueil</a></li>
```

[Page test](http://localhost:8888/wordpress/page-d-exemple/)
Skip to menu toggle button

`

Answer (score 0):

Add width attribute, it should move to the right in that case. Because currently width of navigation div is 100% so it has no where to move.

Comment: thank you for your help ! Need to add width attribute to main-navigation ?

Comment: yes, I mean add it to container that should float on left

Comment: also, remove margin:auto; because it actually sets it to center as well.

Comment: right, I removed it. But now, buttons are almost on the left side unless the container is larger than before :(

Comment: did it but doesn't change anything :( I put `.main-navigation {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
 } `

Comment: Edit the question, add css code, html code, so I can try it on my pc

Comment: It's a huge template, if I send you only this file it will not work :( Maybe faster if you add Reykjavik theme to your themes. Or if you want I could send you the project by mail ? Idk :)

Comment: We don't need whole project, just code rrlated to navigation

Answer (score 0):

Change ul width to 100% and `text-align` to `right`. Child li will be display `inline-block` so they will behave like a text and move to right side.

Comment: Thank you @vivek for your help ! So it should be : `.main-navigation-container ul {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
}`     right ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution, which is not the best way I thought but resolved.
It is to set :

`.main-navigation {    position: relative;   margin: auto;    margin-right: 0px;    }`

Because setting width at 100% it goes over the logo (**test** in the example).